# Python MySQL reads the data wrong for Timestamp(3)

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I recently met with a weird problem about SQL timestamp.
I created a table and the column was like

`` `time` TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT '1970-01-01 08:00:01.000' ``
And I manually inserted `2021-03-18 17:00:32.123`
And what I read through python mysql.connector is `2021-03-18 17:00:32.000123` ?????

Seems like I found the rule, then I changed it to `TIMESTAMP(1)`. Guess what I got `2021-03-18 17:00:32.000001`
Obviously, it's the way in contrast, what could be the problem, thanks

--- Update---

For the python code, there's nothing special

```
cursor.execute("select time from table")

times = list(cursor)
```

And from the debug console, I can see the time is incorrect, as well as the timestamp in UNIX, like

```
unixTime = times[0].timestamp()
```

The Unix time will be something like XXXX.000123 instead of XXXX.123

But I can get the correct result from `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, like

```
cursor.execute("select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) from table")
```

So I think it seems like python mysql lib seems didn't get or convert the format correctly.

Comment: Let's see the Python code

Comment: @Strawberry Hi, some updates, but I think there's nothing special